# Use a string as a condition in Laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, string, conditional-statements

I have users adding texts with conditions. Participants to a test can view the texts depending on their results

An example of the text they enter is as follows

```
BEGIN0[als 1 == true en 4 >= 5]
Concgratulations, You are passed
EINDE0
BEGIN0[als 1 == false en 4 >= 5]
You failed the test but passed the math module
EINDE0
```

Through string replacements I have then the checks as follows

```
0 == true && 6 >= 5
0 == false && 6 >= 5
```

for example 1 participant has failed the test but math score was 6.

I need to remove the text within

```
BEGIN0[als 1 == true en 4 >= 5] and EINDE0
```

I'm able to remove it if I skip the test so that is no issue. The issue however is that I need to test that string condition is true or not

When I do

```
$condition = "0 == true && 6 >= 5"
$check = eval($condition)
```

I get syntax error, unexpected end of file.

Not sure how to go from here.

I tried using the eval or just an if statement but not working.

The assert method is also not functioning in php8 so that is also not an option

Is there any option for checking this string condition without having to chop it up?

Comment: Your question was closed quickly, so it cannot be answered anymore. Did the "duplicate" answer help you? Anyway, you get a syntax error because there's a syntax error in the `$condition` variable you're trying to evaluate. Yes, it's that obvious. To correct this use something like: `$condition = "return 1 == true && 6 >= 5;";`. The missing semi-colon was the syntax error, and you need to return something to get something back from the `eval()` function. Do not skip reading the **caution** on the [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) page.